# how can I list and save the list of all the files with a particular extension in a file and all its subfolders

Tags: windows

I would like to create a list I can save of files with a particular extension. I'd like to know the directory location and size of each file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, for the current directory and below you can use (to search for .jpg files, for example)

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.jpg > FilstList.txt`

It's similar if you want to search a different directory:

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "C:\MyFolder" *.jpg > FilstList.txt`

There are ways to change the output format if needed.

Comment: Thank you!!! This works perfectly. I am not familiar with the Powershell. This is incredibly useful in finding, cleaning and organizing my many years of files.